# Get reference to current object

Tags: swift, macos

My goal is to safe a reference from the button, label or textfield inside a variable.
The problem is that I don't know on which control the user tapped.
I am having a simple application which looks like this:

[image]

The user can touch any control.

It is easy enough with just those three controls because I can drag in a action. But if I am having many of them I can't handle them all over the action methods. Is there a general way in which I can safe a reference to the control in a variable so that I can know which of the controls is the active one?

**Edit**

As suggested I am using a function and assigning the variable to the sender of the function. This is how it looks in code:

```
var currentObject: NSTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTextfield.action = #selector(myAction)
}

func myAction(sender: NSTextField)
{
    print("aktuell: \(sender)")
    currentObject = sender
}
```

As you can see this only works for a NSTextfield. Is there a way in which the function works for every control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `tag` attribute for each item, and then you can check `sender.tag` to identify which object is calling it.

To set the tag, select the Attributes inspector in Storyboard (upper right side - middle button of Utilities) and look for this section:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please look at my edit, do you know how to solve this?

Comment: If you really don't need any other information about the object, you can modify your function to be `func myAction(sender: AnyObject)` and then control-drag all items to that.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that with this way I can't access the currentObject.frame which I have to use later

Comment: Change the `AnyObject` to `NSView` then (or better yet, conditionally unwrap via `if let view = sender as? NSView){}`) - all these controls should be a subclass.